# Asp.Net And c# Html page export into excel with chart image

Tags: export-to-excel

I have a web page that is prepared with ASP.Net as an attachment. I want to export this page to excel on the server side. The methods I tried;

1. I got the table in Excel format with Response.write. But I could not
   assign graphics.
2. I wanted to convert the graphics to data: base64 format. But it could not be displayed in Excel.
3. I do not want to convert the graphics to .png format and link them, because it has to be a permanent report. Link can be deleted.
4. I tried interop with Excel in C#. But I could not put the HTML table into cell. I have to write cell cell. And will I be able to
   embed an image in it?
5. How can I export this HTML page to Excel in this way?

Any ideas?

[Html Page screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6QiTn.png)

Answer (score 2):

**1.** It doesn't work to export the chart to an html page unless the chart is transformed to an image. You need to **build a different html and append the image to it**. This solution it won't export a real Excel file, but an HTML with XLS extension. Most programmers blame this practice and also you will get an warning that the file format is invalid when the file is opened with the latest MS Excel versions. MS Excel only recognize the html file and adjust the data to its spreadsheet.

**2.** You will need to transform your chart to an image jpg, png, gif. The solution depends by what you use to display the chart. **Export the chart to image  and append the image with img tag**.

**3.** If it is a permanent report, you might consider leaving the chart as png on the server side and not saving a temporary file. But this might overflow the hdd on server side. It depends on how many reports you have.

**4.** With Interop you cannot just export the html, you need to build the Excel file step-by-step, add the sheet, add the cells and add the chart. Yes, you can also embed the chart. But **Interop is not recommended on the server-side**:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/257757/considerations-for-server-side-automation-of-office

**5.** The **best solution is to use an Excel library**. There are plenty of such libraries, you need to choose the one that best suits you:
- [Open XML SDK](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30425) for XLSX file,
- [NPOI](https://npoi.codeplex.com/) for XLS or XLSX file,
- [EPPLus](http://epplus.codeplex.com/) for XLSX file,
- [EasyXLS](https://www.easyxls.com) for both XLS or XLSX file
- or any other that you may find.
Some of the libraries have useful methods that will allow you to import the html data, but the chart will need to be added separately.

Comment: Thanks, alex. I understood that it was not easy. I think it's time to use the Open XML SDK, the microsoft solution.